# ordering a union with two selects by two different columns in each select

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The query is pretty straight forward as it follows:

```
SELECT postId, postContent, postDate FROM posts UNION 
ALL SELECT commentId, commentContent, commentDate FROM comments 
ORDER BY postDate DESC, commentDate DESC
```

Instead, getting the results ordered I get a mysqli warning `mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given`

Please help.

the php code is as it follows

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
echo $row['postId'];
echo $row['postContent'];
echo $row['postDate'];
}
```

---

```
postId    postContent     postDate
-------------------------------------
1    |   sample post1    | 03-02-2019
-------------------------------------
2    |  sample post 2    | 04-02-2019
```

this is the posts
and this is the comments

```
commentId    commentContent     commentDate
--------------------------------------------
1        |   sample comment1    | 03-02-2019
--------------------------------------------
2        |  sample comment2     | 04-02-2019
```

Comment: in heidi sql i get `unknown column commentDate` when executing the statement

Comment: The column names are inherited from the first select in the union so commentdate does not exist for the order by,

Comment: how should i proceed to order them by date in a list?

Comment: Can you back track a bit. How do you know a comment belongs to a post? It would help if you added sample data and expected output as text to the question.

Comment: i need to display them individually and no relation between

Comment: ordering is working but i cant access comments right now

Comment: You need to publish your php code.

Comment: @DuduClau . . . You should provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You can try echoing out the variables as `echo $conn;`, `echo $query;`... By the way try to convert the second variable from `$query` to `$query1` ...->  `$query1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)) { .....`

Comment: is working and rewritten already tried

Comment: Thre's no `commentContent` column in your result, those comments are also named `postContent` (the first Select of a set operation determines the resulting column name)

Comment: Consider adding a dummy column to distinguish comments from posts

Comment: how to do it as an alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using an inner query provided all of the three columns have the same data type,
and
remove `, commentDate DESC` from the `ORDER BY` clause, since `commentDate` is also considered as to be `postDate`.

```
SELECT q.*
  FROM
  ( 
   SELECT postId, postContent, postDate FROM posts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT commentId, commentContent, commentDate FROM comments 
   ) q
 ORDER BY postDate DESC
```

Comment: who is `q` is it a alias kind of?

Comment: @DuduClau an arbitrary alias which's required for the subquery.

Comment: @DuduClau Did you used this logic :  `$result = mysql_query("SELECT q.* FROM (.....")` and then invoke `mysql_fetch_array($result)`

Comment: used `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

Comment: @DuduClau I don't have a much knowledge of php but I can guess it needs a boolean argument inside parantheses, such as `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT postId, postContent, postDate
FROM posts
UNION ALL
SELECT commentId, commentContent, commentDate
FROM comments 
ORDER BY postDate DESC, commentDate DESC
```

Without the `ORDER BY`, the result set would have three columns with the names `postId`, `postContent`, and `postDate`.  These can be used in the `ORDER BY`.  In fact, `commentDate` will be renamed `postdate` in the result set.

So, this `ORDER BY` will work:

```
ORDER BY postDate DESC
```

I doubt that is what you really want, though.  If I were to speculate, I would find the following useful:

```
SELECT p.postId, p.postDate, p.postContent, NULL as commentDate, NULL as commentContent
FROM posts p
UNION ALL
SELECT p.postId, p.postDate, c.commentId, c.commentContent, c.commentDate
FROM comments c JOIN
     posts p
     ON c.postId = p.postId
ORDER BY postDate DESC, postId DESC, commentDate DESC
```

Comment: there's no way accessing the comments only with union right?

Comment: @DuduClau . . . If you only want the comments, then you don't need `union` at all.  You can just write a `select` query on the comments table.

Comment: i need to get the comments and the posts how do i do this?

Comment: @DuduClau . . . This answer provides the comments and the posts.  If none of the answers here really suit your needs, then ask a *new* question, provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.